# ImportError: cannot import name 'PyDotnet'

Tags: python, .net, .net-assembly

I've using dotnet.seamless to include C# code into my project. It works properly on my Win10 PC. Now I try to install it on a Windows Server 2008 and get the Error:
"ImportError: cannot import name 'PyDotnet'". In the site_packages I have the same folder "dotnet" and "dotnet-1.2.1.dist-info".
My code to create the C# assembly is:

```
# Import Py.NET module
import dotnet.seamless
# Source of the Example C# class
src = '''
//*** DLL laden
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System;
using System.Text;
//*** Namespace definieren
namespace WebRequest {
    //*** Klasse definnieren
    public class WebReq {
        //*** Vars
        private string UName;
        private string PWord;
        private string ProxyName;

        //*** additional code

    }
}
'''
# Build module
dotnet.build_assembly(src, 'WebRequest.dll', [], '')
```

Is there a elementary difference between the Win10 PC and the Win 2008 Server? Or do I miss somme modules on the Server?

Answer (score 0):

i know this is probabbly a dead thread in the mean time, but just for reference for other people looking at this:

you do need to have the correct MSVC CRT, for version 1.3.1 this is the 2017 version, for 1.2.1, it is the 2015 version - [source](https://bitbucket.org/pydotnet/pydotnet/wiki/Home)

so install the correct c++ redistributable and you should be fine